# Overlapping an icon on React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'd like to have an element overlapping onto an image in react native. I'm new in react native but could do this in CSS in 3 lines of code:

container in position relative.
element in position absolute + bottom: 20px.

Here is my react native code and a screenshot of what it looks like.

```
     <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.profileImage}
        source={{uri: blabla}}
      />
      <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
        <ActionIcon
          name={'mode-edit'}
          color={colorBrand}
          onPress={() => console.log('test')}
        />
      </View>
      <List containerStyle={styles.list}>
        <ListItem
          title={'Account Settings'}
        />
        <ListItem
          title={'Notifications'}
        />
        <ListItem
          title={'Terms & Conditions'}
        />
        <ListItem
          title={'Privacy Policy'}
        />
        <ListItem
          title={'Log Out'}
        />
    </ScrollView>
```

and StyleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  profileImage: {
    height: 250
  },
  list: {
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 0
  },
  iconContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    right: 10,
    bottom: 40,
    marginBottom: -60,
    zIndex: 1
  }
})
```

So it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

So it looks like exactly like I want it. But I am not liking that `zIndex`, nor that negative `bottomMargin`.

I first tried with a container of the iconContainer in position relative, then the iconContainer in position absolute. But to have it displayed you had to set a height. Then you have a white space full width and of the set height with the icon at the right. Which pushes the list down and adds a big white space.

Is there any other options?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add the css property, `position: 'absolute'` to the element you want to overlap.

Comment: This will work and to adjust the overlapping view you can play around with top, bottom, left and right just like you would in css

Comment: so you mean something like 
`iconContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    right: 10,
    top: 210,
    position: 'absolute'
  }`... but then the button is under the list, still need the zindex. Also I don't particularly like that way either. That means that if I change the height of my photo I would have to change that `top: 210` value also. I want it to be relative to the natural DOM position of the element, which should be just under the picture and above the list.

Comment: Try adding that 'pen' edit icon at the very bottom of all the other elements, with the above css property mentioned. You can also try adding `marginTop: any size you prefer` to the same icon styling.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to wrap your **image** and **icon** in a div and then play with **position** css

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #5ab985;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports">
  <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was about react native this looks like react for the web